# How to allow writing locally on read-only NFS Partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, pxe-boot

I created my own PXE/NFS network boot server on Ubuntu 12.04 as explained [here](http://www.serenux.com/2011/04/howto-create-a-diskless-workstation-that-boots-from-pxe-using-ubuntu/). I can write to files on client side if I change `/etc/exports` file like this on server side:

```
/srv/ubuntulivecd/        *(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I want to change files only locally. I mean this shouldn't change the file on NFS partition if I write to the file on local. If i change `rw(read-write)` option to `ro(read-only)`, I can't change files (as expected) because of permissions. Is there a way to change files locally or temporary(all files have to be removed after reboot or power off) on client side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the client, you can copy the files to **tmpfs** (the same a live-cd boots to). You need to set a *union* type FS (**aufs**) between the RO filesystem on NFS and a *tmpfs* RW filesystem on your local machine.

```
example for tmps:
$ mount -t tmpfs no_device /tmp
```

now everything you do on /tmp will work on ramfs

```
example for union:
$ ls dir1
subdir
$ ls dir1/subdir
file1
$ ls dir2
subdir
$ ls dir2/subdir
file2
$ mkdir dir_union
$ mount -t aufs -o dirs=dir1=rw:dir2=ro no_device dir_union
$ ls dir_union
subdir
$ ls dir_union/subdir
file1 file2
```

notice the **dir1=rw** and **dir2=ro**. now you can `$ rm dir_union/subdir/file2` , which should be *ro*, but in the union you can modify it and you will get no error. In fact only the differencies are mapped. If you do

```
$ ls -la dir_union
file1 .wh.file2
```

where .wh.file2 is a file that mappes the differencies.

The same with a CD rom:

```
$ mount -o ro /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
mount -t tmpfs no_device /mnt/rw
mount -t aufs -o dirs=/mnt/rw=rw:/mnt/cdrom=ro no_device /mnt/union
```

Here you will see all the original files of the CD-rom in /mnt/union. If you modify them, the differencies are mapped, the files can be changed in /mnt/union, but the original files in /mnt/cdrom stay unchanged.

Now, as exercice, do it for a NFS mount ;)

cheers